# Python unit test cover except block

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-cov

I have the following function:

```
ClassB:
  def do_something():
    temp = ClassA()
    try:
      return temp.methodA()
    except CustomError:
      return False
```

I want to unit test this function simulating that `methodA` of `ClassA` throws `CustomError` and then veryfing that the result of function `do_something` returns false. My code:

```
@pytest.fixture
def class_b_fixture():
  return ClassB()

@patch('ClassB.ClassA')
def test_do_something_error(class_a_mock, class_b_fixture):
  class_a_mock.return_value.methodA.side_effect = CustomError()
  assert not class_b_fixture.do_something()
```

When I run this test, it fails, the message saying that the error was raised. Why? I mean, this error should be caught by except. If I write it like this:

```
@patch('ClassB.ClassA')
def test_do_something_error(class_a_mock, class_b_fixture):
  class_a_mock.return_value.methodA.side_effect = CustomError()
  with pytest.raises(CustomError):
    class_b_fixture.do_something()
```

The except block is never executed, however the test passes. I've read serveral post about this (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69146845/python-unit-test-is-not-covering-code-inside-the-except-block)) and they all use `with pytest.raises` so why it doesn't work?

Comment: If you except the error it is not going to be raised, it will as you correctly mentioned return `False`. It will only raise if an error other than CustomError is raised.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that CustomError required one argument (message) and it was custom error - I ended up patching this error with mocking class of error defined by me and then I was able to correctly cover the `except` case.